# HTML Textarea with image uploader

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, textarea

Ihave a comment box that works but would like to add the option to upload an image. the image would then be displayed in the text area at the bottom sort of like facebook does.

the code on the page member-index.php is:

```
 <form action="../login/comment-exec.php" method="POST">
    <textarea name="comment" id="feeds" rows="5"  ></textarea>
<input type="hidden" value="<?php $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']?>" name="members_id" />
    <input type="submit"  class="postbutton" name="submit" value="Post" />
    </form>
```

after clicking the submit button it send it to a PHP page that uploads it to Mysql 
how would i integrate an image uploader to this Textarea.

Comment: best upload file tutorial i know: http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You would need to add this in your form:**

`<input type="file" name="imagefile">`
and
`enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your

**I.e.:**
`<form action="../login/comment-exec.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">`

**Then this somewhere in your form handler:**

```
$allowed_filetypes = array('.jpg','.gif','.bmp','.png'); // These will be the types of file that will pass the validation.
$max_filesize = 9999999999; // Maximum filesize in BYTES - SET IN to a low number for small files
$upload_path = './uploads/'; // The place the files will be uploaded to (currently a 'files' directory).

$filename = $_FILES['imagefile']['name']; // Get the name of the file (including file extension).
$ext = substr($filename, strpos($filename,'.'), strlen($filename)-1); // Get the extension from the filename.

// Check if the filetype is allowed, if not DIE and inform the user.
if(!in_array($ext,$allowed_filetypes))
die('The file you attempted to upload is not allowed.');

// Now check the filesize, if it is too large then DIE and inform the user.
if(filesize($_FILES['imagefile']['tmp_name']) > $max_filesize)
die('The file you attempted to upload is too large.');

// Check if we can upload to the specified path, if not DIE and inform the user.
if(!is_writable($upload_path))
die('You cannot upload to the specified directory, please CHMOD it to 777.');

// Upload the file to your specified path.
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imagefile']['tmp_name'],$upload_path . $filename))

// Echo success and the uploaded file.
echo 'Your file upload was successful, view the file <img src="' . $upload_path . $filename . '" title="Anything you want">'; // It worked.
else
echo 'There was an error during the file upload. Please try again.'; // It failed

// rest of your code to be placed below
```

**DB NOTE:** In order to insert the uploaded file or a reference to it in a database, the image file itself will probably need to be renamed along the way, or a unique ID set to it. I don't have any expertise in this field, yet I do know that your records will need to be unique.

For example, people uploading a JPG from an iPod Touch or iPhone etc. The images have a default name of `image.jpg`. Anyone uploading an image from these devices and not renamed, will automatically overwrite the previous uploaded `image.jpg`; just food for thought.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure about nesting uploading data into a textarea but here is a good set of image/file upload scripts that may help.

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

You could always run an ajax call to this script that loads the result of the upload into the textarea...or a div below the text area to show the user what they uploaded. Hope it helps...

Answer (score -1):

You wouldn't want to send the file at the same time as the form if you are doing in like facebook does. When you upload a picture to facebook (or most of the popular sites) it actually uploads the image to their server before it submits the text part of the form.

There are a few ways to do this, the easiest way to add it to your code is to use the HTML5 FileReader class (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader), what it does is load a base64 encoded version of the content of the file, set that to a field in your form, then construct the file on the other end.

`<form action="../login/comment-exec.php" method="POST">
     <textarea name="comment" id="feeds" rows="5"  ></textarea>
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']?>" name="members_id" />
    <input type="hidden" name="filedata" value="" />
    <input type="file" onchange="loadFile(event);" />
    <input type="submit"  class="postbutton" name="submit" value="Post" />
</form>`

for the loadFile event on the change you will need to look into the FileReader, its farily straightforward but a bit too long to give as an example, here is a great link which also supports drag and drop: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/

Comment: I'm not quite sure why you would want to use FileReader for this purpose.  This could potentially add a LOT of additional client-side processing time to your application, depending on the size of the file.  This really isn't the ideal use-case for FileReader.  I'm also not quite sure why you would not want to send the file and the comment in the same request.  Can you expand on your answer?

Comment: I was giving him a starting point for drag/drop support and uploading the images before sending the comment itself.

Comment: FileReader has nothing to do with drag and drop support. Also, there isn't any reason why you cannot send the file and comments in the same request, even with DnD support.